# HTTPError 401 with Google Slides API & OAuth2 on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-slides-api

I'm trying to use the Google Slides API on Google App Engine, and despite using the Google code samples (specifically for OAuth2 & the Slides API on App Engine), I'm running into problems.

Here is my App Engine code, with unnecessary cruft removed (everything's in main.app).  What I'm doing is trying to posting a string from an HTML form and then build a blank presentation.  I've already used the Slides API with a simple script that I prototyped; I'm now trying to make this self-serve via an App Engine app, but it's the change in authentication that's tripping me up.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client.contrib import appengine
from google.appengine.api import memcache

CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """[omitted]""" % CLIENT_SECRETS    

http = httplib2.Http()
service = discovery.build('slides', 'v1', http=http)
decorator = appengine.OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

class SlideBuilder(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required
  def post(self):
    programslug = self.request.get('programid')
    presoname = str(programslug) + ' Mentors'

    presentationbody = {
        'title': presoname
    }
    presentation = service.presentations().create(body=presentationbody).execute()
```

I want to point out that I downloaded the most recent client_secrets.json directly from the API console, so that should match up correctly for CLIENT_SECRETS.

The error I'm getting (on dev server; but it's also on the live app) is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedc/pm-tools/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.py", line 644, in check_oauth
    resp = method(request_handler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedc/pm-tools/main.py", line 113, in post
    presentation = service.presentations().create(body=presentationbody).execute()
  File "/Users/jedc/pm-tools/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedc/pm-tools/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations?alt=json returned "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">
```

It feels like there's something subtle but dumb that I'm doing here.  I'd appreciate any help or pointers to figure out what that is!

Answer (score 0):

This error happening because your http is not authorized with the credentials.
To authorize the http with the credentials you should use the decorator.

```
decorator = appengine.OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)
http = decorator.http()
service = discovery.build('slides', 'v1', http=http)
```

This will fix your problem.
For further reference [read this app engine decorators documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#decorators) from Google